# Можно ли дождаться полной загрузки <video>?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть видеофайл ([пример](https://andreymal.org/files/bbb-test/bbb-with-duration.mp4), 25 МиБ) — я заранее знаю, что он небольшой и поместится в кэш, но для усложения задачи предположим, что его длительность заранее не известна ([другой пример](https://andreymal.org/files/bbb-test/bbb-without-duration.mp4), тоже 25 МиБ). Я хочу дождаться его полной загрузки и только после этого начать воспроизведение, чтобы гарантированно ничего не лагало, например.

К своему большому удивлению я обнаружил, что у тега `<video>` отсутствует событие `load`. Есть события `progress`, `loadeddata` и `canplaythrough`, но что с ними делать — непонятно. Мне попадались попытки посчитать окончание загрузки по сравнению длительности, но, во-первых, в надёжности этого метода есть сомнения, а во-вторых, это не сработает, если длительность в принципе неизвестна.

В связи с этим у меня возникают вопросы:

- будет ли браузер в принципе загружать видеофайл до конца, или он его всего лишь немного забуферизует?
- если будет, то можно ли отловить момент завершения загрузки?
- если не будет, то можно ли отловить момент, когда браузер перестал совершать дальнейшую загрузку? (UPD: нашёл событие `suspend`, но вопрос про полную загрузку ещё актуален)

Ниже в два одинаковых сниппета с разными видеофайлами для поиграться.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onload = () => console.log("onload не срабатывает");
video.onprogress = (event) => {
  console.log(`progress ${event.timeStamp}, duration: ${video.duration}`);
};
video.onloadeddata = () => console.log("loadeddata");
video.oncanplaythrough = () => console.log("canplaythrough");
video.onsuspend = () => console.log("suspend");
```

```html
<video
  id="video"
  src="https://andreymal.org/files/bbb-test/bbb-with-duration.mp4"
  controls
  preload="auto"
  style="margin-bottom: 100vh">
</video>
```

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onload = () => console.log("onload не срабатывает");
video.onprogress = (event) => {
  console.log(`progress ${event.timeStamp}, duration: ${video.duration}`);
};
video.onloadeddata = () => console.log("loadeddata");
video.oncanplaythrough = () => console.log("canplaythrough");
video.onsuspend = () => console.log("suspend");
```

```html
<video
  id="video"
  src="https://andreymal.org/files/bbb-test/bbb-without-duration.mp4"
  controls
  preload="auto"
  style="margin-bottom: 100vh">
</video>
```

Comment: А вот Chrome, похоже, в принципе отказывается воспроизводить этот видеофайл, пока он не загрузится целиком, хех. С одной стороны, это в принципе то что мне нужно прямо сейчас, с другой стороны — а вдруг я однажды захочу воспроизвести частично загруженный видеофайл, а хром мне это не позволит?) Чудны дела ваши, браузеры...

Comment: Можно попробовать прогнать видео в скрытом `iframe`. Т.е. быстро перемещать последнее доступное время диапазонов `seekable` - `video.currentTime = video.seekable.end(i)`. И подловить событие `ended`, тогда нам и `duration` знать не надо.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, бразуер будет запрашивать куски видео через range.

Comment: @andreymal, можешь своему серверу присобачить cors-заголовки, чтобы можно было с любого сайта запрашивать?

Comment: @Qwertiy и правда, я перед отправкой вопроса забыл fetch проверить и подумал что cors не нужен. Добавил

Comment: @andreymal, готово - работает :)

Comment: @andreymal, какие-то комментарии к моему ответу будут?

Comment: @Qwertiy не будут, ответ не отличный, потому что костыль, но щито поделать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, я просто смотрю - не принимаешь - вот и подумал, что чем-то не подошло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Нет, браузер грузит кусок файла и останавливает загрузку.
2. Можно попробовать загрузить файл самостоятельно через fetch.
3. Из скачанных через fetch данных можно создать ссылку - тогда уж точно все данные будут и не потребуется полагаться на кэширование.

```js
fetch("//andreymal.org/files/bbb-test/bbb-with-duration.mp4")
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    var video = document.querySelector('video')
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    video.hidden = false
    video.play()
  })
```

```css
video { display: block; max-height: calc(100vh - 16px); margin: auto; }
```

```html
<video controls hidden muted>
```